# How do I generate a clean (ready to release) build in CMake?

Tags: cmake, build

For the record, because this seems like there should be an obvious, well-known way to do it: I can't find any docs on how to do this - all I find is people looking to do a "clean" of their built files when I search for this.

When you build out-of-source in CMake, the resulting directory does not exclusively contain your built executable and other files. CMake leaves all its cache and makefiles, as well as other intermediate files, lying around - for example, the `CMakeFiles` directory, the `CMakeCache.txt`, `Makefile`s, `.cbp`, `.ilk`, `.pdb`, etc. - meaning if I wanted to release the results of said build, I'd need to (automatically or manually) either remove excess cmake files, or copy all my generated files elsewhere manually, before I am ready to release. This would be tedious for projects that require a specific structure in the output directory, or have many output files (e.g. an `assets` folder full of dozens of built asset files - now polluted with CMakeFiles et al.)

When building with CMake, can I not only perform an out-of-source build where intermediate files (as seen above) end up out-of-source, but where the resulting cmake binary directory is *also* separate and kept free of polluting by CMake and extra compiler output? (e.g. resulting in a `build/output` directory that cleanly contains all the actual built files with proper directory structure.)

Comment: The proper way is to NOT "release" build directory, but **install** the project. That way you have precise control on which files should be installed and where. If you want, you may pack installed directory into the archive or whatever package type. CMake also provides CPack utility for create a package from a project.

Comment: This issue is not limited to using CMake.  The general method is to install the project in a clean location and package the installed files.  The GNU make manual calls this a staged installation and uses DESTDIR as a prefix to be used in all install rules to support staged installations.